# npm --inspect-brk not stopping with chrome 62

Tags: node.js

I enter the following command...

```
node --inspect-brk --experimental-modules test.mjs
```

But when I open up `chrome:\\inspect` it can attach but it just runs through the script with out hitting a breakpoint. Is it my version of Chrome or something?

Comment: Have you tried closing all chrome processes?

Comment: Yeah it seems that if I keep the window open add a break point, close it and redebug it works stopping at my breakpoint